# Typoscript image change every 15 days

Tags: image, typoscript

I would like to make a change of image say every 15 days. Or twice a month. When the date is between the 1 and 15 is an image, and if it is from 16 to 30 another, so on, are 24 images in the year. I would like it to be the typoscript that manages the change of the image.

I took the following typosript:

```
lib.headerlogo1 = COA
lib.headerlogo1 {
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
    divSem.cObject = TEXT
    divSem.cObject {
        data = date:U
        strftime = %U 

        current = 1
        setCurrent.data = date:U
        setCurrent.wrap = |/2
        prioriCalc = 1
    }
}

20 = FILES
20 {
    references {
        data = levelmedia: -1, slide
    }

    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj {
        file.import.dataWrap = {file:current:storage}:{file:current:identifier}
        #file.import.listNum = 0
        altText.data = file:current:title

        # Affiche bien la valeur de : divSem
        #stdWrap.insertData = 1
        #stdWrap.wrap = <div class="banner{register:divSem}">|</div>
    }

    # insertData = 1
    insertData = 1

    # IT'S FAILLED !!
    begin = {register:divSem}
    maxItems = 1 
} 

30 = TEXT
30 {
    stdWrap.insertData = 1
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="{register:divSem}">|</div> 
}
}
```

The problem is that I can not start the value of the registry `begin = {register:divSem}` ... It always starts at 0! Do you have an idea ? The display of the registers in `30 = TEXT` is correct.

Do you have a good idea to modify the typoscript?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, instead of `begin = {register: divSem}`, I did this:

```
    begin.cObject = TEXT
    begin.cObject {
            value = 0
            value.override.cObject = CASE
            value.override.cObject {                    
                key.data = register:divSem
                1 = TEXT
                1.value = 1

                2 = TEXT
                2.value = 2

                ...

                24 = TEXT
                24.value = 24

                default = TEXT
                default.value = 2
            }
    }
```

Maybe there is more simple, if you have an idea, I'm interested.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You found the important detail: you need a `.cObject` to fill in any data in the simple property.

Why so complicated with a `CASE` that outputs the same as the key?

So the simplest way would be:

```
begin.cObject = TEXT
begin.cObject.data = register:divSem
```

maybe this also worked like you do in `.30`:

```
begin = {register:divSem}
begin.insertData = 1
```

and a more direct way of your `.30`:
instead of an `.insertData` for a `.wrap` use `.dataWrap`

```
    begin.stdWrap.dataWrap = {register:divSem}
    :

30 = TEXT
30.dataWrap = <div class="{register:divSem}">|</div>
```